# Does the giant coconut crab in Moana live underwater?

Tags: moana

In the movie *Moana*, the characters fall into a giant cave with a giant coconut cave named Tamatoa. This environment looks like it is underwater:

- Moana encounters giant coral, anemones, and clams here.
- In some scenes, it appears that there are circling fishes above them.
- Fish drop from above to feed Tamatoa.

But the characters do not create bubbles, do not swim here, and are there for a long time.

Is this area underwater? What is the explanation for this strange habitat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are in [Lalotai](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Lalotai), the realm of the monsters.

> Also known as the Realm of Monsters, the entrance to Lalotai can be accessed atop a high mountain on a remote island. The passageway (a pit) leads to an undersea environment home to a number of exotic, demonic and ferocious creatures — one of which being **Tamatoa**, a villainous giant crab.

The realm exists under the sea, but is not *in* the sea:

> Lalotai is derived from two proto-Polynesian words: "lalo" means "below" and "tai" means "the sea." Together, they form a term that means "below the sea" or "under the ocean". Lalotai is also known as "the underworld".

So they aren't surrounded by water, but are in a magical realm, and can be assumed to be breathing air, or whatever passes for an atmosphere there.